# Why I cant create Drawer Navigation in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import Home from "./screens/Home";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import Singup from "./screens/Singup";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home}></Drawer.Screen>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login}></Drawer.Screen>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Singup" component={Singup}></Drawer.Screen>
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

**And my code throw this error:
Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:8 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue**

Comment: What are your react-navigation and react-navigation/drawer versions?

Comment: 8.3.1 both of them

Comment: 8.3.1 version does not exist in both libraries... Can you check them from package.json?

Comment: 6.4.1 react-navigation/drawer